# redirect using htaccess only for specific url

Tags: .htaccess

if user hit `my_website.com` then he should redirect to `my_website.com/abc` but if he hits `my_website.com/xyz` then he can visit normally.

How can i do this using .htacess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://my_website.com/abc [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 5):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my_website\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^$ /abc [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.